# Access enum in structure in ctypes in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to access C++ library in Python and initialize and start GSM module in my controller. The GSM class is okay, but I need to pass values to it's configuration. The C++ declaration:

```
typedef enum _gsmEvent_e{
       GSM_NO_SIGNAL = 0, 
       GSM_RING_VOICE, 
       GSM_RING_DATA, 
       GSM_NEW_SMS, 
       GSM_CALL_RELEASED, 
       GSM_RECEIVED_DATA, 
       GSM_FAILURE, 
       GSM_COVERAGE,  
    }gsmEvent_e;
    //EVENT BUFFER
#define EVENTS_BUFFER_SIZE    1024
  
typedef struct _gsmEvents_s{
       gsmEvent_e  gsmEventType;
       char        evBuffer[ EVENTS_BUFFER_SIZE];
       int         evHandled;
    }gsmEvents_s;
  
typedef struct _TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION{
       unsigned char wCode    [ 9];
       unsigned char wMECode  [ 9];
       void  (*gsm_action)( gsmEvents_s * );
    }TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION;
```

In my Python code I'm trying to configure the module, but I having problem with `void  (*gsm_action)( gsmEvents_s * );`. My Python code:

```
#importing libraries etc ...
gsmEvent_e = c_int
GSM_NO_SIGNAL = gsmEvent_e(0)
GSM_RING_VOICE = gsmEvent_e(1)

class gsmEvents_s (Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("gsmEventType",  gsmEvent_e),
        ("evBuffer", c_char * 1024),
        ("evHandled", c_int)

    ]

    def __init__(self, gsmEventType, evBuffer, evHandled
                 ):
        super().__init__(
            gsmEventType,
            evBuffer,
            evHandled
        )


class TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION (Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("wCode", c_char * 9),
        ("wMECode", c_char * 9),
        ("gsm_action", gsmEvents_s),


    ]

    def __init__(self,
                 wCode=b'',
                 wMECode=b'',
                 gsm_action = gsmEvents_s
                 ):
        super(TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION, self).__init__(
            wCode,
            wMECode,
            gsm_action
        )

class GSM:
    def __init__(self):
        ret = c_int(0)
        self.io = IOs()
        self.rtu = RTU()
        self.libGsm = cdll.LoadLibrary("libGSM_Module.so")
        self.gsm_init()

    def gsm_init(self):
        gsmconf = TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION()
        pgsmconf = pointer(gsmconf)
        self.libGsm.GSM_Initialize.restype = c_int
        ret = self.libGsm.GSM_Initialize(pgsmconf)

        self.libGsm.GSM_Start.restype = c_int
        while True:
            ret = self.libGsm.GSM_Start()
            if ret != 0:
                ret = self.libGsm.GSM_Finalize()
                time.sleep(5)
            else:
                break
```

How can I access gsmEvents_e and initialize the GSM?

Comment: "but I having a problem".  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small demo of some C code that looks similar to your API below, and show how to handle an enum and callback nicely:

**test.c**

```c
#include <memory.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef enum _gsmEvent_e {
    GSM_NO_SIGNAL = 0,
    GSM_RING_VOICE,
    GSM_RING_DATA,
    GSM_NEW_SMS,
    GSM_CALL_RELEASED,
    GSM_RECEIVED_DATA,
    GSM_FAILURE,
    GSM_COVERAGE,
} gsmEvent_e;

#define EVENTS_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

typedef struct _gsmEvents_s {
   gsmEvent_e gsmEventType;
   char evBuffer[ EVENTS_BUFFER_SIZE];
   int evHandled;
}gsmEvents_s;

typedef struct _TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION {
   unsigned char wCode[9];
   unsigned char wMECode[9];
   void (*gsm_action)(gsmEvents_s*);
} TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION;

TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION* g_conf;

API int GSM_Initialize(TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION* pgsmconf) {
    // Save off the configuration so the callback can be called by start.
    g_conf = pgsmconf;
    return 1;
}

API void GSM_Start() {
    // Hard-code some event response and call the callback.
    gsmEvents_s event;
    event.gsmEventType = GSM_FAILURE;
    memset(event.evBuffer, 'A', EVENTS_BUFFER_SIZE);
    event.evHandled = 1;
    g_conf->gsm_action(&event);
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct
from enum import Enum,auto

class gsmEvent_e(Enum):
    GSM_NO_SIGNAL = 0
    GSM_RING_VOICE = auto()
    GSM_RING_DATA = auto()
    GSM_NEW_SMS = auto()
    GSM_CALL_RELEASED = auto()
    GSM_RECEIVED_DATA = auto()
    GSM_FAILURE = auto()
    GSM_COVERAGE = auto()

    @classmethod
    def from_param(obj): # allows enum to be used in .argtypes
        if not isinstance(cls, obj):
            raise TypeError('not a gsmEvent_e enumeration')
        return obj.value

class gsmEvents_s(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (("_gsmEventType",  ct.c_int),
                ("evBuffer", ct.c_char * 1024),
                ("evHandled", ct.c_int))

    @property
    def gsmEventType(self): # wrapper to return the enum when referenced.
        return gsmEvent_e(self._gsmEventType)

    # allows structure to print itself
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'gsm_Events_s(type={self.gsmEventType.name}, handled={self.evHandled})'

# callback type
GSM_ACTION = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.POINTER(gsmEvents_s))

class TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("wCode", ct.c_char * 9),
                ("wMECode", ct.c_char * 9),
                ("gsm_action", GSM_ACTION))

# To define a Python callback function, decorate with the callback type
@GSM_ACTION
def gsm_action_callback(gsm_event):
    # callback pointer is dereferenced with .contents
    # __repr__ defined above allows event to print itself
    print(gsm_event.contents)

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.GSM_Initialize.argtypes = ct.POINTER(TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION),
dll.GSM_Initialize.restype = ct.c_int
dll.GSM_Start.argtypes = ()
dll.GSM_Start.restype = None

gsmconf = TGSM_MODULE_CONFIGURATION(b'code', b'mecode', gsm_action_callback)
dll.GSM_Initialize(gsmconf)
dll.GSM_Start()
```

Output:

```
gsm_Events_s(type=GSM_FAILURE, handled=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question, what if I have this c code: ```typedef struct _INET_Events{
       unsigned char evType;
       int           evHandled;
    }INET_Events;
    typedef struct _TINET_MODULE_CONFIGURATION{
       unsigned char  wBearer;                   
       void* wBearerParameters;
       void  (*inet_action)( INET_Events * );
    }TINET_MODULE_CONFIGURATION;```. How can I pass `void  (*inet_action)( INET_Events * );` to python class? Could you please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183164/passing-callback-c-function-to-structure-in-ctypes